# Scrapy: store broken external links and discard the rest

Tags: python-2.7, scrapy

I want Scrapy to store only the external links that are broken (a response code different from 200, 301 or 302) but I'm stuck with this and the script keeps storing every external link on the output file. This is what I'm using:

```
@staticmethod
def remote_file_to_array(url):

    return filter(None, urllib2.urlopen(url).read().splitlines())

@staticmethod
def sitemap_to_array(url):
    results = []
    body = urllib2.urlopen(url).read()
    sitemap = Sitemap(body)
    for item in sitemap:
        results.append(item['loc'])
    return results


def start_requests(self):


    target_domain = self.arg_target_domain
    print 'Target domain: ', target_domain


    self.rules = (

        Rule(LinkExtractor(allow_domains=[target_domain], unique=True),
             follow=True),

        Rule(LinkExtractor(unique=True),
             callback='parse_item',
             process_links='clean_links',
             follow=False),
    )
    self._compile_rules()


    start_urls = []
    if self.arg_start_urls.endswith('.xml'):
        print 'Sitemap detected!'
        start_urls = self.sitemap_to_array(self.arg_start_urls)
    elif self.arg_start_urls.endswith('.txt'):
        print 'Remote url list detected!'
        start_urls = self.remote_file_to_array(self.arg_start_urls)
    else: 
        start_urls = [self.arg_start_urls]
    print 'Start url count: ', len(start_urls)
    first_url = start_urls[0]
    print 'First url: ', first_url


    for url in start_urls:


        yield scrapy.Request(url, dont_filter=True)


def clean_links(self, links):
    for link in links:

        link.fragment = ''
        link.url = link.url.split('
        yield link


def parse_item(self, response):
    item = BrokenLinksItem()
    item['url'] = response.url
    item['status'] = response.status
    yield item
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your best bet would be to use a Downloader Middleware to log the desired responses.

```
from twisted.internet import defer
from twisted.internet.error import (ConnectError, ConnectionDone, ConnectionLost, ConnectionRefusedError,
                                    DNSLookupError, TCPTimedOutError, TimeoutError,)

class BrokenLinkMiddleware(object):

    ignore_http_status_codes = [200, 301, 302]
    exceptions_to_log = (ConnectError, ConnectionDone, ConnectionLost, ConnectionRefusedError, DNSLookupError, IOError,
                         ResponseFailed, TCPTimedOutError, TimeoutError, defer.TimeoutError)

    def process_response(self, request, response, spider):
        if response.status not in self.ignore_http_status_codes:
            # Do your logging here, response.url will have the url, 
            # response.status will have the status.
        return response

    def process_exception(self, request, exception, spider):
        if isinstance(exception, self.exceptions_to_log):
            # Do your logging here
```

That handles some exceptions which may not indicate a broken link (like `ConnectError`, `TimeoutError`, and `TCPTimedOutError`), but you may want to log them anyway.

Comment: Thanks both for your answers. @Rejected, I'm trying to work out a new scraper using your code snippet as a reference but I'm messing it up... Sorry I am just starting with scrapy. When I try to store only external links with DNS Lookup failed response, the scraper keeps retrying DNS lookup failed links and then skips them without storing them.

Comment: This should be used as a [Downloader Middleware](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/downloader-middleware.html#downloader-middleware), and not *directly* incorporated into the spider.  If you add this to your settings file, and fill in whatever you do for logging, it won't impact how the crawler works in any way, but will log the results of failed attempts.  In this instance, it will log all three attempts at the invalid domain (as the Retry Middleware retry a Request 3 times before abandoning it).

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the `errback` argument on the `Request` object, that works like the `callback` but for not accepted response statuses.

I am not sure if that can be also achieved with `rules`, if not you'll need to define your own behaviour